# Tic tac toe with websockets connection

Tags: java, google-chrome, glassfish, websocket, netty

I am trying to make tic tac toe using websockets running on glassfish. I've download [this example](http://kevinwebber.ca/blog/2011/11/2/multiplayer-tic-tac-toe-in-java-using-the-websocket-api-nett.html) form git. Firstly, I want to test it, so I run it as a normal java process on my machine. I also made a tiny change to the tictacto.js

```
  if (typeof MozWebSocket != "undefined") { // (window.MozWebSocket)
    appType = "Mozilla";
  } else if (window.WebSocket) {
    appType = "Chrome";
  } else {
    alert('ERROR: This browser does not support WebSockets');
  }
```

and then

```
    if (appType == "Mozilla") {
     ws = new MozWebSocket(WEBSOCKET_URL);
     //alert('MozWebSocket');
   } else {
     ws = new WebSocket(WEBSOCKET_URL);
     //alert('WebSocket');
   }
```

When I open the test page with FF 10.0 the event onclose is only invoked and I get the status "The WebSocket Connection Has Been Closed." then I open the test page with Chrome 17.0.963.46 m. The status is also "The WebSocket...." but server throws an exception.

```
run:
TicTacToe Server: Listening on port 9000
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:218)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:186)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:359)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:323)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:282)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:202)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

What is the cause? I though about a few possilbe issues:

- I use Netty 3.2.6.Final from JBoss repository. It could use different standard of websockets than the browsers.
- running it as a java process on my machine istead as a webserver. But Netty doesn't have any dependencies that would require it.
- Wrong locations. var WEBSOCKET_URL = "ws://localhost:9000/websocket"; and html location is C:...web\kolo\src\main\webapp\t.html

I am using Netbeans 7.1 and glassfish 3.1

**Fixed project can be found** https://github.com/lukasz-madon/Tic-Tac-Toe-with-WebSocket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be the web socket version.  Here's a [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support) of web socket versions and which browser supports which.

From memory, 3.2.6 only supported HyBi-00.

Try [Netty 3.3](http://netty.io/blog/2012/01/19/).  It supports a number of versions.

Comment: Remember to use the WebSocketX package (and not the WebSocket package which has been left in for backwards compatibility).